# How to get social account (facebook,twitter,snapchat) userid from an AccountManager? Is it possible?

Tags: android, accountmanager

hai i am trying to gather user details like userid,username,email etc stored in accountmanager by social applications from my currently developing application.

I was able to get basic details like

```
{name=myemail@gmail.com,type=com.google}
{name =Facebook,type=com.facebook.auth.logn}
```

As i need more information i thought of using `getUserdata()` **what is the key i should pass in the below method?** Also will i be able gather these data?

```
public String getUserData (Account account, 
            String key)
```

While going through documentation i saw  that `This method requires the caller to have a signature match with the authenticator that owns the specified account.`

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: please checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13244218/5706413